# web3.py ERROR: Failed building wheel for lru-dict, websockets, bitarray, cytoolz, legacy-install-failure

Tags: web3.py

Everytime I try to `python -m pipenv install web3` it does not work.
The errors are for ru-dict, websockets, bitarray, cytoolz.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because you do not have a C compiler installed and need to install one for your machine. If you're on mac, install apple command line developer tools by running this command in the terminal:
`xcode-select --install`  . After installation completes, try reinstalling web3.